# Is there a way to get StreamBuilder to load content slightly before the user scrolls down to it to reduce delay (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

Currently my app loads the information (including pictures) into cards from Cloud Firestore, but it only starts loading the information when it appears on the user's screen. I used FadeInImage in _makeCard to make it a bit more usable while loading, but it's still too slow. Is there a way to make StreamBuilder load, for example, the nearest 10 cards that are off the screen? If not, is there a better way to create a list that is loaded from Firestore? This is my code currently:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Cards').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (context, index) {
          return _makeCard(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]);
        },
        childCount:
          snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data.documents.length : 0,
     ),
  );
})
```

I don't have a lot of experience with coding, so let me know if there is anything I can clarify.